# Get-ChildItem exclude multiple full path

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'd like to use Powershell script that search files greater than 30GB.
But I'd like to exclude from search, multiple files by full path. Files patchs are in external txt file. I try use -notike and -Exclude. But without success. Ewery time I get list of all files. Any sugestions how to do this correctly.

```
$exclude = @(Get-Content c:\exclude.txt)
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users -Include *.* -Recurse | where-object{$_.fullname -notlike $exclude} | where-object {$_.length -gt 35000000000}
```

c:\exclude.txt

```
C:\users\tom\36gb.txt,C:\users\john\38gb.txt
```

I'd like get list of files that not include files from c:\exclude.txt

Comment: since those paths in exclude file are absolute, you can use `$_.FullName -notin $exclude`

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path c:|\Users -File -Recurse | where  Lengeth -gt 300GB | where FullName -notIn $Exclude

Comment: Without success. Path in exclude.txt hould be sepatated with coma or pipe? Or in quotes?

Comment: your file is a single line comma delimited? put the paths one in each line and that should work

Comment: Than You Santiago Squarzon, changing to -notin and put paths in separate lines works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`-notin` comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) but each path in the `exclude.txt` file should be in a new line:

- `exclude.txt`

```
C:\users\tom\36gb.txt
C:\users\john\38gb.txt
```

Then you can do:

```bash
$exclude = Get-Content c:\exclude.txt
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object { $_.Length -gt 30Gb -and $_.FullName -notin $exclude }
```